# How to loop over a text file using while loop?

Tags: python

if I have a text file like:

```
     StudentA:
      10
      20
      30
      40

      StudentB:
      60
      70 
      80
      90
```

I want to make a function :

```
    def read_file(file,student):
        file=file.open('file.txt','r')
```

when I call it,

```
     read_file(file,StudentA)
```

it will show the list like:

```
    [10,20,30,40]
```

How can I do it with a while loop?

Comment: Why do you need to do it specifically with a `while` loop?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you want to read using `while`, `for-loop` will do just fine. But here is a pythonic way to read files.

```
with open(...) as f:
    for line in f:
        <do something with line>
```

The `with` statement handles opening and closing the file, including if an exception is raised in the inner block. The `for line in f` treats the file object `f` as an iterable, which automatically uses buffered IO and memory management so you don't have to worry about large files.

Comment: In this case, a `while` loop makes some sense.  OP only wants to read part of the file.  Rather than inserting a `break` into the `for` loop, you could do it with a `while` loop.  (Although, both ways are a little messy)

Comment: well if you are trying to read only part of a file, either which way you use `break` needs to be used. there is no getting away from that. But what most people miss when trying to read files is - what is that file is not present? what is that file is 1GB in size? these problems  dont occur when one is at unit testing phase but when the code goes to the wild who knows what to expect.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

def read_file(filename, student):
    with open(filename, 'r') as thefile:
        lines = [x.strip().upper() for x in thefile.readlines()]
    if student[-1] != ':':
        student += ':'
    current_line = lines.index(student.upper()) + 1
    output = []
    while current_line < len(lines) and re.search('^\d+$', lines[current_line]):
        output.append(int(lines[current_line]))
        current_line += 1
    return output
```